# How to build a custom widget in JupyterLab with JavaScript

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I have written a simple widget in Jupyter Notebook which is a checkbox table. Now, I am trying to migrate this widget to Jupyter Lab. However, I am unable to find a way to insert JavaScript in a running notebook to build my widget.

I have read the new ipywidget8 tutorial, but I think creating a code package is too heavy for this small feature. I hope to achieve this functionality without building a package, like the ipywidget7 style.

ipywidget8: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.5/examples/Widget%20Custom.html#front-end-typescript

ipywidget7: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/examples/Widget%20Custom.html#Front-end-(JavaScript)

Here is my front-end code:

```js
require.undef("my_widgets");
define("my_widgets", ["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {

  var TableView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({
    // Render the view.
    render: function() {
      this.table_changed();

      // Python -> JavaScript update
      this.model.on("change:table", this.table_changed, this);

      // JavaScript -> Python update
      this.el.onchange = this.input_changed.bind(this);

      // Script
      $(this.el).on("click", ".my-table tbody tr", function (event) {
        if (event.target.type != 'checkbox'){
          $(this).find(".my-chk")[0].click()
        }
      });
    },

    table_changed: function() {
      this.el.innerHTML = this.model.get("table");
    },

    input_changed: function() {
      let value = [];
      let jcheck = $(this.el).find(".my-chk");
      for (let i=0;i<jcheck.length;i++) {
        if (jcheck[i].checked) {
          value.push(i)
        }
      };
      $(this.el).find(".my-table")[0].setAttribute("date-value", value.join());
      this.model.set('value', value);
      this.model.save_changes();
    },
  });
 
  return {
    TableView: TableView,
  };
});
```

Here is my back-end code:

```py
import traitlets
from jinja2 import Template
from ipywidgets import Layout, DOMWidget, register

@register
class TaskTable(DOMWidget):
    _view_name = traitlets.Unicode('TableView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = traitlets.Unicode('my_widgets').tag(sync=True)

    value = traitlets.List([], help="selected").tag(sync=True)
    table = traitlets.Unicode('', help="rendered HTML table").tag(sync=True)

    @traitlets.validate('value')
    def _valid_value(self, proposal):
        proposal['value'] = [int(x) for x in proposal['value']]
        return proposal['value']

    def render(self, head, body):
        thead = ['#'] + head
        tbody = body
        self.table = template.render(head=thead, body=tbody)
        
template = Template(STATICS_TaskTable)

STATICS_TaskTable = """
<table class="my-table">
<thead>
<tr>
  {%- for th in head -%}
  <th>{{ th }}</th>
  {%- endfor %}
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {%- for row in body -%}
  <tr>
    {%- for cell in row -%}
      {%- if loop.first -%}
        <th><input class="my-chk" type="checkbox"> {{ cell }}</th>
      {%- else -%}
        <td>{{ cell }}</td>
      {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
  </tr>
  {%- endfor -%}
</tbody>
</table>
"""

w = TaskTable()
w.render(['foo', 'bar'], [[1, 'A', 'S'], [2, 'D', 'F']])
w
```

I tried to add jQuery and RequireJS to the page, but only got an error message `Error displaying widget: model not found`

I could not found a page like "front-end-javascript" in the ipywidget8 tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You must note that for Jupyter Notebook. Instead of relying on requirejs to define and load modules, **JupyterLab uses npm packages and Typescript for frontend development.**

So in JupyterLab, widgets are usually packaged and distributed as npm packages. You need to create a new npm package for your widget.

install it by using - `npm install --save @jupyter-widgets/base`

in src, create your file like the below one -

```
// src/TableView.ts
import { DOMWidgetView } from '@jupyter-widgets/base';

export class TableView extends DOMWidgetView {
    render() {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.model.get('table');
    }

    // add more here
}
```

Compile your Typescript file and **update the widget entry point** in the compiled js file

```
// lib/TableView.js
define(["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {
    // ... your code comes here
});
```

Once done, you can include your widget in JupyterLab, you need to update your labextension.

for src/index.ts file -

```
// src/index.ts
import {
    JupyterFrontEnd,
    JupyterFrontEndPlugin
} from '@jupyterlab/application';

import {
    IJupyterWidgetRegistry
} from '@jupyter-widgets/base';

import {
    TableView
} from './TableView';

 //Initialization data for the widget extension.
 const extension: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
    id: 'my_widgets',
    autoStart: true,
    requires: [IJupyterWidgetRegistry],
    activate: (app: JupyterFrontEnd, registry: IJupyterWidgetRegistry) => {
        registry.registerWidget({
            name: 'my_widgets:TableView',
            version: '1.0.0',
            exports: {
                TableView
            }
        });
    }
};

export default extension;
```

dont forget to update the package.json file to add this line - `"main": "lib/index.js",`

and this -

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && jupyter labextension install ."
}
```

Now you can start the jupyter Lab -

```
jupyter labextension develop . --overwrite
jupyter lab
```

This is a simplified version of what I have shared but you can make it more complex once the widget starts loading.

Hope it helps.